# show that there are no $a,b \geq 1,n \geq 2$ such that $a^n−b^n \mid a^n+b^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that there are no $a,b \geq 1,n \geq 2$ such that $a^n−b^n \mid a^n+b^n$.

That's what I have tried so far:

We suppose that $a^n-b^n \mid a^n+b^n$

Then , $∃k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^n+b^n=k(a^n−b^n)$

Let $d=(a,b), a_1=\frac{a}{d} ,b_1=\frac{b}{d}$  , then $(a_1,b_1)=1$

So,we have :

$$d^n \cdot a_1^n+d^n \cdot b_1^n=k(d^n \cdot a_1^n−d^n  \cdot b_1^n) \Rightarrow a_1^n+b_1^n=k(a_1^n−b_1^n) \Rightarrow (k−1)a_1^n=(k+1)b_1^n $$

But...how could I continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see that $a^n-b^n \mid a^n + b^n \iff a_1^n - b_1^n \mid a_1^n + b_1^n$.

Now observe that $a_1^n + b_1^n = (a_1^n - b_1^n) + 2b_1^n$, so

$$a_1^n-b_1^n \mid a_1^n + b_1^n \iff a_1^n - b_1^n \mid 2b_1^n.$$

Since $\gcd(a_1,b_1) = 1$, the latter means $a_1^n - b_1^n \mid 2$.

Comment: Why is $a_1^n-b_1^n \mid 2$ a contradiction??

Also,do I have to prove that if $$(a_1,b_1)=1,\text{ then also } (a_1^n-b_1^n,b_1^n)=1$$ ? Or is it known?

Comment: Suppose a prime $p$ divides $a_1^n-b_1^n$ and $b_1^n$. Then it divides $b_1$, and it divides $(a_1^n-b_1^n)+b_1^n = a_1^n$, therefore it also divides $a_1$. But then $p\mid \gcd(a_1,b_1)$. And $a_1^n-b_1^n\mid 2$ implies $\lvert a_1^n - b_1^n\rvert \in \{1,2\}$. Find out why that cannot be.

Comment: It can be that $$a_1=2k+1 \text{ and } b_1=2m+1 \text{ OR } a_1=2k+1 \text{ and } b_1=2m \text{ OR } a_1=2k \text{ and } b_1=2m, \text{ right? }$$

So,it is:

$$a_1^n-b_1^n=(2k+1)^2-(2m+1)^2 \text{ OR } a_1^n-b_1^n=(2k+1)^2-(2m)^2$$

Or am I wrong? Then,would $a_1^n-b_1^n$ have the number $4$ as as factor,or not??

Comment: It need not have a factor $4$, e.g. $5^3 - 3^3 = 98 = 2\cdot 7^2$. Without loss of generality, let $a_1 > b_1$. Then $a_1^n - b_1^n \geqslant (b_1+1)^n-b_1^n$.

Comment: And is it a property that $(b_1+1)^n-b_1^n>2$ ??

Comment: $n \ge 2 \land a > b > 0 \rightarrow a^n - b^n \ge 3$, since $(a+1)^n = a^n + na + \dots + 1$.

Comment: @evinda As NovaDenizen said. For $n,b\geqslant 1$ you get that e.g. from the binomial theorem.

Comment: Could you explain it further to me?? I haven't really understood it...

Comment: @evinda For $b_1 \geqslant 1$ you have $$(b_1+1)^n - b_1^n = \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} b_1^{n-k}\right) - b_1^n = \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}b_1^{n-k} \geqslant \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k} = 2^n - 1.$$ For $n\geqslant 2$, that is $\geqslant 3$.

Comment: A ok..I understand...thank you very much!!! Do I have to check also the case $b_1 \geq a_1$ ??

Comment: @evinda That's by symmetry, then $a_1^n - b_1^n \leqslant -3$. (Note that $b_1 = a_1$ cannot be, because then $a = b$, and $0 \nmid a^n+b^n$ for $a\geqslant 1$ and $b\geqslant 1$.)

Comment: And at this case,do we have to say that:

$$a_1^n-b_1^n \leq (b_1+1)^n-b_1^n=2^n-1$$

? But...would this be a contradiction??

Comment: @evinda Sorry, I don't understand the question. We have $\lvert a_1^n - b_1^n\rvert \geqslant 2^n-1 \geqslant 3$ for $n\geqslant 2$ and $a\neq b$.

Comment: @DanielFischer If it would be, $b_1>a_1$,$a_1^n-b_1^n \mid 2$ would mean that $a_1^n-b_1^n<0$ divides $2$,right?? And,if $k \mid l$,then also $-k \mid l$ ,or not?? Because of this property,we just have to check the case $a_1> b_1$ ?? Or have I understood it wrong??

Comment: @evinda Yes. Since $k\mid I \iff (-k)\mid I$, we can without loss of generality assume $a_1 > b_1$.

Comment: Nice!!!I understand!!!!Thank you very much!!!!